# Creating a class with CodeTypeDeclaration and adding members to it

Tags: c#, codedom, jscript.net

i am declaring a class with the help of CodeTypeDeclaration like this :

```
CodeTypeDeclaration targetClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration(sType);
```

I can add a constructor  :

```
 CodeConstructor constructor = new CodeConstructor();
 constructor.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
```

Or a member field  :

```
 CodeMemberField myField = new CodeMemberField();
 myField.Name = fieldName;
 myField.Type = new CodeTypeReference(fieldType);

 targetClass.Members.Add(myField);
```

But i am trying to add any kind of line , for example a constant declaration :

```
const addressFilteresErrorCounters: UInt32 = 0x0000AE77;
```

Can i do this without using CodeMemberField ? 
Maybe somehow i can add to the class a CodeSnippetStatement, so let's simply say , add some line to the class by the using the force and not filtering the declaration line with the CodeMemberField ?

Maybe smth like this :

```
    targetClass.Members.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement("var n = 2"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, does the code using snippet work?

Comment: No, it was just an example for the easy add. I couldn't do it, so now i am opening the file and i'm adding the needed lines manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a `CodeSnippetStatement` directly to a class. You can, however, add them to a `CodeMemberMethod` for example:

```
CodeMemberMethod method = new CodeMemberMethod();
method.Name = "DoSomething";
method.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
method.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement("var n = 2;"));
```

Although you don't need to resort to a `CodeSnippetStatement` to add a constant. You can use:

```
CodeTypeDeclaration exampleClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("GeneratedClass");
CodeMemberField constant = new CodeMemberField(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.UInt32)), "addressFilteresErrorCounters");
constant.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Const;
constant.InitExpression = new CodePrimitiveExpression(0x0000AE77);
exampleClass.Members.Add(constant);
```